# Vaadin component styling confusion

Tags: java, css, vaadin, styling

I am trying to access the individual parts of elements which you have to go through the shadow DOM.  I have been trying to do it like in this guide: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki/1.-Style-Scopes

Adding this code to my shared-styles.html file works fine:

```
vaadin-text-field {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Then for accessing specific parts of the element to style, it shows to access it like this:

```
#shadow-root (open)
  <style>
    :host {
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
  </style>
```

And that you can access the specific parts (input-field in this case) like this:

```
#shadow-root
  <style>
    [part="input-field"] {
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
  </style>
```

I just do not understand how the last 2 code blocks are supposed to identify that they are changing 'vaadin-text-field' as it is nowhere in the code snippet.  Adding those snippets alone of course do not work..  I feel like it's something simple I am overlooking.  Thank you so much, I appreciate all of the great help available for Vaadin!

Comment: Updated URL for the above Style Scopes link is: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin#style-scopes. The content was moved from wiki to readme. Currently the old wiki pages still link forward to the readme, but the wiki pages might get removed in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the [Stylable Shadow Parts](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin#stylable-shadow-parts) section of the docs. It gives some examples that would be helpful.

Shortly, to style a Vaadin component (like `<vaadin-text-field>`) you would need to add your styles into the shadow DOM of the component. In order to do that define a style module with a `theme-for="vaadin-text-field"` attribute and place your custom styles there. Before the first render Vaadin components look for style modules with the `theme-for` attribute and pick styles from there.

```html
<dom-module id="my-input-theme" theme-for="vaadin-text-field">
  <template>
    <style>
      [part="input-field"] {
        border: 1px solid gray;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<vaadin-text-field label="Username"></vaadin-text-field>
```

Here is a live example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/theming-vaadin-components-npm-p3?path=custom-theme.js:4:0

The example above would change the styles of *all* `<vaadin-text-field>`s in the app. If you want to style only some text fields, use a theme or an attribute selector:

```html
<dom-module id="my-input-theme" theme-for="vaadin-text-field">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host([theme~="bordered"]) [part="input-field"] {
        border: 3px solid hotpink;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<vaadin-text-field label="Themed" theme="bordered"></vaadin-text-field>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm trying to get the last part to work, but i'm writing this in all Java and there is no method to set 'theme' to a specific button.  The first example is working for all buttons, but how would I set the specific button theme in java?  thanks for the help!

Comment: Vaadin 10 has APIs for almost any kind of DOM manipulation from server-side Java. In order to set an attribute on a `TextField` component, first access it's corresponding DOM element with the `getElement()` method, and then use the Element API to set an attribute: `textField.getElement().setAttribute("theme", "bordered");` More details in the docs: [working with UI components](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/components/tutorial-component-basic-features.html#element), [the Element API](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/element-api/tutorial-properties-attributes.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i needed.  If you wouldn't mind answering another question, is there a way to programatically set the background color of a vaadin-grid row based on something inside of it? like if a value is positive, set it to green, if negative, set row background to red.  Not sure how I would go about doing that

Comment: Happy to help! Would you mind posting your other question separately from this one?

Comment: Thank you so much Viktor!  I have added the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747059/vaadin-10-grid-style-individual-row-based-on-contents

Comment: Updated URL for the above "Stylable Shadow Parts" link is: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin#stylable-shadow-parts. The content was moved from wiki to readme. Currently the old wiki pages still link forward to the readme, but the wiki pages might get removed in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much! The part to style only one specific component with the attribute selector helped me alot!

Answer (score 1):

The last examples would require you to actually edit the contents of the style-tag inside the component.

At the bottom of that page you'll find a **Read next:** [Adding Styles to Local Scope.](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki/2.-Adding-Styles-to-Local-Scope)

Comment: Updated URL for the above "Adding Styles to Local Scope" link is: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin#adding-styles-to-local-scope. The content was moved from wiki to readme. Currently the old wiki pages still link forward to the readme, but the wiki pages might get removed in the future.