# Vaadin 10 grid style individual row based on contents

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am using a Vaadin grid to display incoming information and update it in realtime.  I have been able to style all of the rows by accessing the DOM like so:

```
<dom-module id="my-grid" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
    <template>

        <style>
            [part="row"] {
                height: 27px;
                font-size: 14px;
                max-height: 27px;
            }

        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

What I am trying to do is set specific styling to certain rows based on the contents of the data of the row.  Basically I have a column of booleans and if it's true, I want the row to have a green background, and if it's false I want that row to have a red background.  Now sure how I would do this in my Java code or my `shared-styles.html`.  Thank you so much!

I have seen this example for programatically styling a column based on a condition, but not a row..

```
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(people);

grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(person -> {
    if (person.getGender() == Gender.MALE) {
        return new Icon(VaadinIcons.MALE);
    } else {
        return new Icon(VaadinIcons.FEMALE);
    }
})).setHeader("Gender");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of now (Vaadin 10, vaadin-grid 5) there is no API for adding custom attributes/classes to individual rows in a grid. It is possible to implement this use case in your application code, but the implementation might be not very efficient.

One approach would be defining a custom renderer for each column of the grid to wrap each cell contents in an extra div, and add classes / attributes to the wrappers. You can use a `TemplateRenderer` to minimize the memory / performance impact of these wrappers:

```java
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setDataProvider(...);

ValueProvider<Person, String> cssClassProvider = (person) -> {
    String cssClass = "my-grid-cell";
    if (person.getAge() <= 16) {
        cssClass += " junior";
    } else if (person.getAge() >= 60) {
        cssClass += " senior";
    }
    return cssClass;
};

grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<Person>
        of("<div class$=\"[[item.class]]\">[[item.age]]</div>")
            .withProperty("class", cssClassProvider)
            .withProperty("age", Person::getAge));
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<Person>
        of("<div class$=\"[[item.class]]\">[[item.name]]</div>")
            .withProperty("class", cssClassProvider)
            .withProperty("name", Person::getName));
```

And then you can set the background of the grid cells based on the CSS class (in `shared-styles.html`):

```html
<custom-style>
  <style>
    .my-grid-cell.junior {
      background-color: coral;
    }

    .my-grid-cell.senior {
      background-color: darkmagenta;
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>
```

However, that would not look great with the default Lumo theme styles for the Vaadin Grid. In order to make your grid look OK you'll need to override some of these default styles:

```html
<dom-module id="my-grid-theme" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
  <template>
    <style>
      [part~="cell"] {
        min-height: 0;
      }

      [part~="cell"] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<custom-style>
  <style>  
    .my-grid-cell {
      min-height: calc(var(--lumo-size-m) - 2 * var(--lumo-space-xs));
      padding: var(--lumo-space-xs) var(--lumo-space-m);
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>
```

Comment: Thank you Viktor, I will try this out later today!  I am blown away by your help, can not thank you enough!  If you are interested I would pay you for Vaadin coaching!